# Importing Selenium files to Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, junit4, performance-testing

In Ubuntu OS, using Eclipse I have written Selenium - Junit code and I have exported the files from Eclipse (jar files) and pasted it to lib > junit folder of Jmeter
But Jmeter is not identifying the jar files in junit sampler. Request you to suggest best methods if any I can use

Thank you

Comment: yes I tried by Re Starting Jemter

Comment: Probably your problem is related to the classpath. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath

Comment: Hi Avaneesh, Any error log you could provide?

Comment: There are NO errors, I am able to execute my Selenium script & also able to export it as jar file, But jmeter is not identifying that jar file

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, hope it will be helpful to other:

Lib Files of Selenium needs to be placed / replaced in the Lib folder of Apache jemter